# When two "be" verbs are used in one sentence, should the second be omitted?

Tags: grammar, be, omissibility

For example

> He is a teenager and [is] from South Sudan.

Is it necessary to delete the second "is" in parentheses?

Comment: In this case it's better to write "He is a teenager from Sudan." Or you could say-- " He is a teenager and he is from Sudan." The former conveys the same info in a concise manner.

Comment: It's not _necessary_ to omit it, but there is no reason to include it.

Comment: Sometimes the verb is repeated for emphasis or when the thrust of the sentence changes. For instance we might say "He is a teenager from Syria _and is_ looking for political asylum".

Comment: It’s also sometimes hard, in speech, to differentiate between “... and is from Sudan” and “... and he’s from Sudan”

Comment: To "be", or not to "be", that is the question.